# How to send web pages to a Kindle from Firefox?

Tags: kindle, calibre, conversion, send-to-kindle, cloud-based

I'm looking to send web pages to a Kindle from Firefox, so am looking at:

https://www.online-convert.com/

Unlike Calibre, there's no convenient share button.  There *is* an upload button for "the cloud" -- but can I get this to work with the Kindle?  Perhaps through Calibre?

Perhaps there's a better work-around to send web page content to a Kindle from Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

What type of Kindle do you have? Most of them support browsers, even though some are quite basic. So one option would be to simply view the website on the kindle itself, no?

If this is not sufficient please can you clarify why in your original question.

Comment: I find browsing from the kindle awkward, don't you?  What I found was "send to kindle" from fivefilters.org which, so far, is free and works.  The other one, online-convert.com, is more powerful but has a two step process where they e-mail the `.mobi` file.  I also configured pocket to send me articles on a regular basis, which is kinda neat.

Comment: @Thufir nice one. I used to use IOS save to Books feature to effectively create PDFs of web pages to view later on my ipad. There are always several options of these kind of things. Most web browsers support a print to PDF, which you could then transfer to the kindle relatively easily, see this link https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200767340

Comment: Yeah, their "we may limit" always spooks me, though.  The advantage to `mobi` being that the text flows better than `pdf`, not sure how or what fivefilters.org is sending but it seems okay.  They do choke on IBM websites, and a few others, though -- but pretty good.  Can't argue with free :)