# How to send a long web page to a Kindle device?

Tags: kindle, calibre, conversion, html, send-to-kindle

What's the [simplest](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/2/9853) solution to [send](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/8094/9853) a long web page to a Kindle device?

Normally I use [five filters](https://fivefilters.org/kindle-it/), but it sometimes barfs.  In [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/) case I'm guessing it's simply the size of the page.

I'm looking for a one-click [alternative](https://ebook.online-convert.com/) to the five filters paste pad (which was able to send the page).

Comment: on linux there's also a "pastebin" utility which sends text files to a pastebin of your choice.  Between wget, lynx, et. al. I'm sure there's some CLI tool tool which *could* exist to interact with some API somewhere somehow...Or, I guess, there's always Calibre...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Amazon's official browser extension :) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-to-kindle-for-google/cgdjpilhipecahhcilnafpblkieebhea